# fbdidLogin never called

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my ViewController

```
- (IBAction)loginBtn:(id)sender 
{
    facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"231190276934148" andDelegate:self];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
        facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
        facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
}

    if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
        NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            @"user_likes",
                            @"user_about_me",
                            @"user_photos",
                            @"friends_about_me",
                            @"friends_activities",
                            @"read_stream",
                            @"publish_stream",
                            nil];
        [facebook authorize:permissions];
    }

    NSLog(@"asdoiffijd");
}

- (IBAction)btnRequest:(id)sender 
{
    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self];
}

- (void)fbDidLogin
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExiprationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];
    NSLog(@"fbDidLogin!");
}
```

In my appDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    return [facebook handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

I think    `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation` should be called before the `fbdidLogin` but I can't complete this part `[facebook handleOpenURL:url];`

in stackoverflow, `[[controller facebook] handleOpenURL:url];` will resolve problem,
but i can't do this. Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In their documentation, they suggest that you need this in your app delegate.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/

When I first tried this, I putting it in another object that I use for interacting with Internet sources and it didn't work. When I put it in my app delegate, it worked fine. I concluded that when they say "Modify the application delegate ...", they *really* mean the app delegate.

Comment: Yeah.. I have tried in appDelegate and it really worked.
but can I make the button for FB login in appDelegate?

Comment: No, but in your view controller you can have a line that says something like `YourAppDelegate *appDelegate = (YourAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;` and then you can start using your Facebook object or its methods at that point.